# Laravel 5.7 foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

Basically I'm trying to upload my migrations to the database, but I'm having some issues because I'm trying to reference columns from tables that aren't created yet. I thought about migrating them 1 by 1, but for example I have group and user tables. The group has a creator (user), and the user have a group. So I cannot reference them in the same time, because they're not created.

Here is my error:

```
PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `vote-system`.`#sql-1a08_37` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")")
```

Group Migration

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('groups', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->integer('created_by')->unsigned();
        $table->timestamps();

        // Relationships
        $table->foreign('created_by')->references('id')->on('users');
    });
}
```

User Migration

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->ipAddress('ip');
        $table->integer('votes_left');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->integer('group_id')->unsigned();

        // Relationships
        $table->foreign('group_id')->references('id')->on('groups');
    });
}
```

Comment: I think you can remove the foreign key from your `users` table

Answer (score 1):

The correct way would be to create migrations for creating/dropping tables with lower timestamps (so these are executed first),

then just add/drop all your foreign keys with migrations with timestamps greater than previously used. This way you won't get into issue like you do now.

Example of the migration to add foreign keys:

```
class AddForeignKeysToMyTableTable extends Migration {

    public function up()
    {      
        Schema::table('my_table', function(Blueprint $table) 
        {
            $table->foreign('my_field_id', ...
```

You may also wanna try some generator to create all the migrations for you. This one will make sure all your table-making migrations run before the ones to add foreign keys:

https://github.com/Xethron/migrations-generator